# Different string initialization yields different behavior?

Tags: c

How come when I use the following method, to be used to convert all the characters in a string to uppercase,

```
while (*postcode) {
    *postcode = toupper(*postcode);

    postcode++;
}
```

Using the following argument works,

```
char wrong[20];
strcpy(wrong, "la1 4yt");
```

But the following, doesn't, despite them being the same?

```
char* wrong = "la1 4yt";
```

My program crashes in an attempt to write to an illegal address (a segfault, I presume). Is it an issue with not `malloc`ing? Not being null-terimanted? It shouldn't be...

Through debugging I notice it crashes on the attempt to assign the first character as its uppercase.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault/1614739#1614739

Comment: +1 for avoiding `*postcode = toupper(*postcode++);` or the equally bad `*postcode++ = toupper(*postcode);` :)

Comment: For crying out loud... this exact same question pops up at least twice a week.

Comment: you were a novice once as well ephemient

Comment: Yes, but searching for "c segfault" on Stack Overflow alone gives you the answer within the top 5 hits.  Being a novice does not exclude you from searching for and reading documentation on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char* wrong = "la1 4yt";
```

This declares a pointer to a string constant. The constant cannot be modified, which is why your code crashes. If you wrote the more pedantic

```
const char* wrong = "la1 4yt"; // Better
```

then the compiler would catch the mistake. You should probably do this any time you declare a pointer to a string literal rather than creating an array.

This, on the other hand, allocates read/write storage for twenty characters so writing to the space is fine.

```
char wrong[20];
```

If you wanted to initialize it to the string above you could do so and then would be allowed to change it.

```
char wrong[20] = "la1 4yt"; // Can be modified
char wrong[]   = "la1 4yt"; // Can be modified; only as large as required
```

Comment: is there not a way that only the memory required to hold "la1 4yt" will be allocated in initialising the [mutable] string? declaring it in the array is too verbose for my taste.

Comment: Sure is, you can omit the size and let the compiler calculate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
char * whatever = "some cont string";
```

Is read-only.

Answer (score 2):

In the second variant, `"la1 4yt"` is a constant and therefore is in a read-only segment. Only the pointer (`wrong`) to the constant is writeable. That's why you get the segfault. In the first example however, everything is writable.

This one might be interesting: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html and http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html and http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arypbref.html

Answer (score 2):

See [Question 8.5](http://c-faq.com/charstring/strlitinit.html) in the C FAQ list.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
char wrong[20] = "la1 4yt";
```

the compiler **copies** the elements of the string literal `{'l', 'a', '1', ' ', '4', 'y', 't', '\0'}` to the corresponding elements of the `wrong` array; when you do

```
char *wrong = "la1 4yt";
```

the compiler assigns to `wrong` the address of the string literal.

String literals are `char[]` (arrays of char), not `const char[]` ... but you cannot change them!!

**Quote from the Standard:**

```
6.4.5 String literals
6   It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided
    their elements have the appropriate values. If the program
    attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.
```

When I use a string literal to initialize a `char *`, I usually also tell the compiler I will not be changing the contents of that string literal by adding a `const` to the definition.

```
const char *wrong = "la1 4yt";
```

---

*Edit*

Suppose you had

```
char *test1 = "example test";
char *test2 = "test";
```

And the compiler created 1 single string literal and used that single string literal to initialize both test1 and test2. If you were allowed to change the string literal ...

```
test1[10] = 'x';       /* attempt to change the 's' */
printf("%s\n", test2); /* print "text", not "test"! */
```