# Segmentation fault in equating a char pointer value to some char

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this C code causing a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault)

```
char* string = "abcd";
```

now when i try to change some character of this string i get segmentation fault

```
*string = 'p';
```

or

```
string[0] = 'p';
string[0] = 52;
```

Can someone please explain me the reason that why is it happening.

Thanks

Alok.Kr.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108832/write-permission-for-char

Comment: Also [Different string initialization yields different behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647273/different-string-initialization-yields-different-behavior)

Comment: If this is only C, then remove the C++ tag, if this is C++, try avoiding names of types in the standard library as they might be confusing (i.e. do not call your strings `string`)

Comment: "equate" is used incorrectly in the title. Variables are not "equated", they are assigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write `char* string = "abcd";` the string "abcd" is stocked into the static data part of your memory and you can't modify it.

And if ou write `char* string = 'p';`, that's just wrong. First, you try to declare a variable with the same name (string) and, worse, you try to assign a char value to a char pointer variable. This doesn't work. Same thing : `char[0] = 'p';` really means nothing to your compiler except a syntax error.

Comment: sorry for all the typing errors, i guess i was so sleepy that i typed all those things.

Comment: Ok. So as I said "string[0] = 'p';" can't work because string is static data and is read-only.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are non-modifiable in C.  This has been asked and answered many times before, though it isn't too easy to search for.

Comment: That's why it's a good habit to write

    char const * p = "hello"

rather than

     char * p = "hello"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify `string`, declare it as an array, not a pointer to a string literal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "hello world";
    string[0] = 'H';
    string[6] = 'W';

    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

```
$ /tmp/hello
Hello World
```