# Why can't compiler derive string length for array of strings?

Tags: c, string, stack, memory-management

**Note:** This question was influenced by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726350/problem-with-processing-individual-strings-stored-in-an-array-of-pointers-to-mult/1726380#1726380).

The following is valid C code:

```
char myString[] = "This is my string";
```

This will allocate a string of length 18 (including the `\0` character) on the stack and assign the specified value to it.

However, the following:

```
char myStrings[][] = {"My 1st string", "My 2nd string", "My 3rd string"};
```

is not valid, giving the error "array type has incomplete element type".

So I have to specify the array like this:

```
char myStrings[][20] = {"My 1st string", "My 2nd string", "My 3rd string"};
```

Where 20 is a number which is larger than my longest string.

This compiles and works as expected.

If the compiler can dynamically sense the string length when allocating a single string on the stack, why can't it do so for an array of strings?

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, this is not a real life programming problem I am experiencing - this is just morbid curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing is to "sense" the length of one string. Another thing is to calculate the maximum of lengths of many strings. There's a certain intuitive qualitative difference between the two. So, the language authors probably decided that the former is simple and useful, but the latter is too compilex and less useful.

Comment: +1 Good answer - was more along the lines of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Why not do:

```
const char* myStrings[] = {"My 1st string", "My 2nd string", "My 3rd string"};
```

Comment: Sometimes you need modifiable strings

Comment: +1 @jeffamaphone very nice.
@pmg, I think, the intention of the person asking this question, is just to create a constant string.

Comment: As pmg noted, it would mean that the resultant strings were read-only.

Comment: @Alphaneo - no the question was more curiosity than anything else, but being modifiable would be useful too.

Comment: True, but I've found that this is almost always what you really want in these cases.  The other case is he really wants a vector<string> at which point, if he's stuck in C, he gets to write his own.

Answer (score 3):

Because the compiler sees this

```
char myStrings[][20] = {"My 1st string", "My 2nd string", "My 3rd string"};
```

as

```
char myStrings[][20] = {(char*), (char*), (char*)};
```

Then, errrr ... hmmm, with "compiler magic", it can copy the characters in those `(char*)` to the array myStrings[0] and myStrings[1], ....

---

*Edit*

You cannot have "jagged arrays" in C. Suppose you had

```
char my_strings[][] = {"a", "ab", "abc", "foo foo fo foo foo", "abc", "ab", "a"};
```

`my_strings[0]` needs the same space as `my_strings[3]` because the language mandates array elements to be contiguous, and it needs a specific size of each array.

```
my_strings in memory
    'a' '\0' '\0' ...  '\0' but must be a definite size
    'a' 'b'  '\0' ...  '\0' definite size
    ...
    'f' 'o'  'o'  ...  '\0'
    ...
```

To find the maximum size and initialize the array(s), the compiler would need to do two passes over the string literals.

Comment: The "excess" character memory for each string will not contain garbage. It will be filled with zeroes. The general philosophy used by C language when it comes to initialization is that something is either completely uninitialized (the whole thing is garbage) or completely initialized (the parts that don't have s user-supplied initializer are zero-initialized). For example, when you declare `char s[100] = "a"` not only `s[0]` and `s[1]` are initialized, but also all elements from `s[2]` to `s[99]` are guaranteed to be zero-initialized.

Answer (score 2):

char myString[] = "..." is a 1-Dimensional array and it will work.
char myStrings[][] = {"...", "..."} is a 2-D array with (possibly) different row length, and this will not work.
char myStrings[][20] is a 2D array with fixed row length and it will work.

According C standards, compiler cannot sense the length of string in 2D arrays.

But I guess, it is possible in Java.

Comment: It's possible in Java because arrays of strings are always arrays of pointers.