# why is this code causing runtime error?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char *a = "Hello ";
  const char *b = "World";

  printf("%s", strcat(a, b));
  system("PAUSE");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: String literals are not modifyable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault/1614739#1614739

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are writing data at a memory location that you do not own.

Indeed, when running strcat, you are appending the characters of string b right after the characters of string a. But you haven't claimed for the memory after the string a.

Answer (score 2):

When you are concatenating b to a you are writing into memory you didn't allocate,