# Unable to dereference

Tags: c++

In the following code, why is not possible to do this dereferencing: `*arr = 'e'`. Shouldn't the output be the character `'e'`?

```
int main ()
{
    char *arr = "abt";
    arr++;
    * arr='e'; // This is where I guess the problem is occurring.
    cout << arr[0];

    system("pause");

}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00a91da1 in Arrays.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00a97839.

Comment: If "abt" is a constant string literal, then why does the following code modify the same constant literal: int main (void)
{
 char arr[]= "abt";

 arr[0]='e';
 cout<<arr[0];

 system("pause");

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this C code causing a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main ()
{
    char *arr= "abt"; // This could be OK on some compilers ... and give an access violation on others
    arr++;
    *arr='e'; // This is where I guess the problem is occurring.
    cout<<arr[0];

    system("pause");

}
```

In contrast:

```
int main ()
{
    char arr[80]= "abt"; // This will work
    char *p = arr;
    p++;    // Increments to 2nd element of "arr"
    *(++p)='c'; // now spells "abc"
    cout << "arr=" << arr << ",p=" << p << "\n"; // OUTPUT: arr=abc,p=c
return 0;    
}
```

This link and diagram explains "why":

> http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268
>
> *Memory Layout of C Programs*
>
> A typical memory representation of C program consists of following
>   sections.
>
> 1. Text segment
> 2. Initialized data segment
> 3. Uninitialized data segment
> 4. Stack
> 5. Heap
>
> And a C statement like const char* string = "hello world" makes the
>   string literal "hello world" to be stored in initialized read-only
>   area and the character pointer variable string in initialized
>   read-write area.

Comment: The second "fixed" example is wrong, you can't do `arr++;` on an array.

Answer (score 3):

`"abt"` is what is called a string literal constant, any attempts to modify it result in undefined behavior `*arr='e';`.

Comment: Then why I am able to do the following:int main (void)
{
 char arr[]= "abt";

 arr[0]='e';
 cout<<arr[0];

 system("pause");

}

Comment: @JohnNash, [it had been already asked and answered long before you posted...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: `char arr[] = "abt";` is an array of characters, `char *arr= "abt";` is a pointer to a string literal that resides in read-only memory.