# why segmentation fault in second code?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this C code causing a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault)

```
char array[6] = "kapil";  
array [0] =  'K';
```

this code runs ok.
but **following code produce segmentation fault ?**

```
char* array = "kapil";  
array [0] =  'K';
```

why first does not produce seg-fault.

Answer (score 3):

`char* array = "kapil";` declares a string literal and is equivalent to `const char*`.  This may well exist in read-only memory and cannot be modified.

Strictly speaking, attempts to modify it result in undefined behaviour but in practice a seg fault is likely.

Answer (score 1):

`char* array = "kapil";` using this type of declaration, it copies `kapil` in read-only context, you can change its contents.