# C function using strcat with strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcat

I'm trying to learn C. So I've challenged myself to create a function called `two()` which will effectively "double" a string.

```
two("foo") // => "foofoo"
```

But I'm having trouble using `strcat()` in conjunction with pointers. Here's what I have:

```
char *two(char *foo);

int main() {
    printf("The value of two(\"foo\") is %s", two("foo"));
}

char *two(char *foo) {
    return strcat(foo, foo);
}
```

It compiles but errors on run. Why?

I have a feeling the error resides in using `strcat` with pointer strings.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is this string reversal C code causing a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault) and large number of other questions suffering from the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't allocate space to hold two copies of your input string.

`strcpy` copies strings.

`strcat` appends one string onto another.

`malloc` allocats bytes on the heap that should be `free()` later.

```
char *two(char *foo);

int main() {
    char * ptr =  two("foo");
    printf("The value of two(\"foo\") is %s", ptr);
    free(ptr);
}

char *two(char *foo) {
    char * ptr = malloc(strlen(foo) * 2 + 1);
    strcpy(ptr, foo);
    strcat(ptr, foo);
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Exactly right, I indicated it needed to be freed and I upvoted the answer below that passes in a buffer.

Comment: Yes, you indicated that it needs to be freed, but you didn't reflect that in your example. (Note: nobody ever gets to see _who_ upvoted anything.)

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple rules of `strcat` you are breaking:

- The first parameter shouldn't be a string literal, because it's
  non-modifiable.
- The first parameter must be large enough for the concatenated string.
- The first and second parameter shouldn't overlap.

Answer (score 4):

The docs say `strcat`

> Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.\

You're passing a constant string `"foo"` to `strcat` as the destination buffer.  Trying to overwrite  constant string is bad.  Even if it weren't constant, you're writing 7 characters over 4 (including the terminating nulls).  This is also bad.

You probably want this:

```
char *two(char *result, char *str)
{
    return strcat(strcpy(result, str), str);
}
```

And when you call it,

```
int main() {
    char buf[40];
    printf("The value of two(\"foo\") is %s", two(buf, "foo"));
}
```

Comment: +1 This is clearly an excellent answer if you wish to pass the destination buffer into the function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are misunderstanding `strcat`. Have a look at [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) link for a brief explanation of what it does. In particular the man page says that

> The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result

You are passing it the same address for both parameters, which means that the strings *overlap*. Also, I can't see how you are allocating the string so I can't tell if there is enough space in the *buffer* / *array* for the resulting string.