# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in a C program

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *Change(char *str,int start,int end)
  {
  if(start==end || start>end){
    return str;
  }

  else{
    char temp=str[start];
    str[start]=str[end];
    str[end]=temp;
    return(Change(str,start++,end--));
  }
  return str;
}


char *Reverse(char *str)
{
   int length=strlen(str);
  return(Change(str,0,length-1));
}

int main()
{
   printf("%s\n",Reverse("program"));
   return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write a recursive function to reverse a string,but it comes the linking error.Please help.I had tried so many times and searched in the Internet,but it can't help.
I guess the most probably place causing the problem is in function Change,but I can't solve with it.

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger at all?... You can catch a seg fault and look at where your code has gone wrong.

Comment: Where is `temp` declared in `Reverse()` ? Please post the actual code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: Use return(Change(str,++start,--end));

Comment: I should have run it in a debugger@Joe.

Comment: It is a mistake which I have corrected it.@zakinster

Comment: I have tried but failed.@ZhiWang

Comment: @luojiebin You actually have two errors in your code (see my answer), if you correct both, your code will work.

Comment: Oh,I find it help.@ZhiWang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string literal (which is a `const char*`) to `Reverse()`, since you can't modify a string literal, your program generates a segmentation fault.

You'll either need to pass a modifiable string to `Reverse()`:

```
char myStr[] = "program";
printf("%s\n",Reverse(myStr));
```

Or you can make a copy of the input string in `Reverse()`:

```
char *Reverse(const char *str)
{
   int length=strlen(str);
   char* temp = malloc(length);
   strcpy(temp, str);
   return(Change(temp,0,length-1));
}
```

In that case, you'll need to free the string returned by `Reverse()`:

```
char* reverseStr = Reverse("program");
printf("%s\n", reverseStr );
free(reverseStr);
```

Also in `change()`, `start++` end `end--` will return the value before they are incremented, you need to use either `++start` or simply `start+1` since you won't use those variables anymore:

```
return(Change(str,start+1,end-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation: You can't modify a string literal. One more thing is that the statement

```
return(Change(temp,0,length-1));
```

will cause compilation error because neither `temp` is defined in the function `Reverse` nor it is globally defined.