# Why does this code raise an Access violation while writing exceptions?

Tags: c

Does anyone know why the following code raises an access violation writing exception?

```
void squeeze_c(char s[], int c)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
        s[j] = '\0';
    }
}
```

I called the function as following:

```
squeeze_c("Test", 's');
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? What do you pass for arguments?

Comment: If you pass a string literal to this function, then it will probably crash.

Comment: I'm going to bet that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: The `s[j] = '\0';` should probably be outside the loop.

Comment: And the bet is correct.

Comment: i passed squeeze_c("Test", 's'); It raised the exception once i and j are both 0

Comment: String literals are *constant*, you are not allowed to modify them.

Comment: reversed the calling function

Comment: but if i changed from s[j++] = s[i]; to s[j] = s[i]; j++;  but it still failed

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with that code so it comes down to two possibilities (probably more, but these are the most common in my experience).

1. You are passing a non-string, something that's not terminated with a `\0` character.
2. You are passing a string *literal,* something you are not permitted to modify.

> Now that you've specifically stated you're calling it with `squeeze_c("Test", 's');`, point two above is the correct one.

---

The former is if you do something like:

```
char str[] = {'n','o',' ','n','u','l',' ','h','e','r','e'};
```

and you can fix that by simply making certain it *has* a `\0` at the end.

---

The latter is if you do something like one of:

```
squeeze_c("this is a literal", 'l');
```

or:

```
char *xyzzy = "another literal";
squeeze_c(xyzzy, 'l');
```

You can fix *that* by ensuring you have a writable *copy* of the literal, something like:

```
char xyzzy[] = "another literal";
squeeze_c(xyzzy, 'l');
```

---

And you really *don't* want to add the `\0` inside the inner loop since it's likely to damage your source string.

Consider if you use:

```
char xyzzy[] = "paxdiablo";
squeeze_c (xyzzy, 'd');
```

The first time through your loop, you'll overwrite the `p` with itself *and then overwrite the `a` with `\0`.* Then you'll exit the loop because the next character found at index `i` will be that `\0` you just wrote to the string).

So it won't so much remove all the `d` characters as truncate your entire string to a length of one.

Instead, you'd be better off with:

```
void squeeze_c(char *s, int c) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    s[j] = '\0';  // moved outside the loop
}
```

This will transform the string as follows (with `|` representing `\0`):

```
paxdiablo|     original string
paxdiablo|     copy p over p
paxdiablo|     copy a over a
paxdiablo|     copy x over x
paxdiablo|     no copy, j now one less than i
paxiiablo|     copy i over d
paxiaablo|     copy a over i
paxiabblo|     copy b over a
paxiabllo|     copy l over b
paxiabloo|     copy o over l
paxiablo||     final placement of \0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's my typo error. The s[j] should be outside the loop. But the exception was raised before that statement.