# Modify a string with pointer

Tags: c, string

This two codes have to change the char `2` in the character `'4'`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
       char *s = "hello";   
       *(s+2)='4';
       printf( "%s\n",s);
       return 0;     
    }
```

When I run this I get segmentation fault while when I run this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
   char *s = argv[1];   
   *(s+2)='4';
   printf( "%s\n",s);
   return 0;     
}
```

I know that there are other methods to do this. What is the difference between the 2 programs?

Comment: Where are you getting the seg fault? on `*(s+2)='4';` ?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first case, you're facing [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by attempting to modify a *string literal*. A segmentation fault is one of the common *side-effects* of UB.

In your code,

```
 char *s = "hello";
```

essentially puts the starting address of the *string literal* `"hello"` into `s`. Now, is you want to modify the content of `*s` (or `*(s+n)`, provided `n` does not go out of bounds), it will actually try to modify that *string literal*. As usually, the string literals are stored in the read-only memory, they are *usually* not allowed to be modified. Quoting from `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*, <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

However, in your second case, you're doing

```
 char *s = argv[1];
```

which is putting the value of `argv[1]` into `s`. Now, `s` points to the *string* contanied by `argv[1]`. Here, the contents of `argv[1]` (or, `argv[n]`, to be general) is not read-only, it can be modified. So, using `*s` (or `*(s+n)`, provided `n` does not go out of bounds), you can modify the contents.

This case is **defined behaviour**, because as per §5.1.2.2.2, *Program startup*

> **The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program**, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

So, the second case is a *special* case while using `argv[n]`, which is by the C standard rules, modifiable.

Comment: This answer is to professional for for person who ask this kind of question.

Comment: @MarekR Sorry, I did not get you.

Comment: For newbie this answer is to hard to understand.

Comment: @MarekR Actually I like to quote directly from the standard so that there is no chance for misconception / misunderstanding. English is not my strong point (not my native language). Would you like to propose any addition to this answer to make it easy? I'll be thankful. :-)

Comment: much better. I'm impressed that you give such big attention to this kind of question.

Answer (score 4):

As Sourav said, attempting to modify a string literal invokes undefined behavior.  If you alternately did the following, it would work fine.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
   char s[] = "hello";   
   *(s+2)='4';
   printf( "%s\n",s);
   return 0;     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
char *s = "hello";
```

you are assigning `*s` to point to the beginning  of a **string literal** which is **non-modifiable**. Which means you can *read* what's there but you can't change it (which is why

```
*(s+2)='4';
```

is giving you a segmentation fault.

In your second case, you are not giving your pointer a string literal, so you can modify it.

In fact, in your second case, you are using `argv`which is **specifically** explained to be modifiable in the c standard.

Answer (score 0):

the literal: 'hello' is in read only memory, so cannot be changed.

Trying to change it causes the seg fault event

Trying to change the array of strings from argv[] has the same problem.  The values are readonly

Trying to change a command line argument causes the seg fault event.

You could use: ' char s[] = "hello"; ' as that will put the literal on the stack, where it can be changed.

You could copy 'strcpy()' after getting the length of the command line argument and performing a malloc() for that length+1