# How do I truncate string with an offset function in c?

Tags: c

I would like to truncate a string with a function.
I am getting the error: **main.c:7: error: lvalue expected**

What am I doing wrong?

```
char *stringtest;

int main() 
{
    &stringtest=strtrunk("hello world!", 3);
    printf("%s", &stringtest);

    return 0;
}

char *strtrunk(char *string, int offset)
{
    int stringlen = strlen(string);
    string[stringlen - offset] = 0;
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Modifying a string literal is Undefined Behavior (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `strtrunk` returns a `char*` and `stringtest` is already of type `char*`. So use

```
stringtest=strtrunk("hello world!", 3);
```

instead of

```
&stringtest=strtrunk("hello world!", 3);
```

`%s` expects a `char*` as its argument and since `stringtest` is already a `char*`, use

```
printf("%s", stringtest);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s", &stringtest);
```

---

The error "*lvalue expected*" occurs because `&stringtest` isn't a valid [lvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-value).

---

Oh, and as mentioned in other answers, modifying a string literal invokes Undefined Behavior.

---

And you need to add a function prototype just after including the headers:

```
char* strtrunk(char*, int);
```

or otherwise simply move the definition of `strtrunk` before the definition of `main`.

Comment: now the error is: main.c:14: error: incompatible types for redefinition of 'strtrink'

Comment: @SimoneGreco Updated answer. In simple words, move `char *strtrunk(char *string, int offset){...}` before `main` or add `char* strtrunk(char*, int);` just after the `#include`s

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes as suggested by CoolGuy. However that won't be sufficient.

You cannot modify a string literal. Even if your program would compile, it would crash since it is illegal to modify the string literal.
Use something i have shown below:

```
char p[20] = "hello world!"
strtrunk (p, 3);
```

Comment: As per your comment on above post, you are missing the prototype of the function strtrunk ().

Comment: i try with 2 compilers on windows "tiny c compiler" and "gcc" in tcc "main.c:7: error: lvalue expected" while in gcc is "error: conflicting types for 'strtrunk' "

Comment: Have you added the prototype?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
char *strtrunk(char *string, int offset);
char *stringtest;
char Char_array[]="hello world!";
int main() 
{
    stringtest=strtrunk(Char_array, 3);
    printf("%s", stringtest);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

char *strtrunk(char *string, int offset)
{
    int stringlen = strlen(string);
    string[stringlen - offset] = 0x00;
    return string;
}
```

Please read this link which explains your problem in detail [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)