# different between *name and name[] in declaring a string

Tags: c, string, variables, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void fit(char *p , int n);
int main(void)
{
    char *mesg = "Hey, Lisa. You look so beautiful! "; // Line A
    puts(mesg);
    fit(mesg , 6);
    puts(mesg);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void fit(char *p , int n)
{
    if(strlen(p) > n)
        *(p + n) = '\0';
}
```

Look at the code above. The function fit is designed to display only the first n characters of a string by putting a '\0' in position n+1. Here comes the problem. If in Line A, *mesg is replaced by mesg[], the program works fine. But *mesg doesn't function. I use vs2012. I know name in *name is a variable so name++ is OK while name in name[] is a constant so name++ isn't allowed. Apart from that difference, shouldn't *name and name[] be the same in declaring a string?

Comment: You can modify a character array, but you can't modify a string literal. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1614723/10077

Comment: It is a historical legacy that does not require `char *mesg` to be `const char *mesg`, but it should be,  Change to `const char *mesg` and the the compiler should error on `fit(mesg , 6);`

Answer (score 3):

In the C language, the following rules apply (some of them don't apply to others like C++):

1. Arrays may degrade to pointers, possibly lossing their constant properties as described in rule 4.
2. Any expression of the form `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x + y)`.
3. A string literal represents a null-terminated array of characters.
4. A variable name `a` for a given array is constant, and is equivalent to `&a[0]`.
5. For any non-constant, non-volatile type `T`, an expression of type `T` may be assigned to a variable name whose type may or not include the constant and/o volatile qualifiers, and if non-qualified would have type `T`, but an expression that constant and/or volatile qualified, and has type `T` when non-qualified, may not be assigned to a variable name that lacks the qualifiers of such an expression.

This implies that all the following assignments all valid:

- `char str[] = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rule 3.
- `const char str[] = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rules 3 and 5.
- `volatile char str[] = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rules 3 and 5.
- `const volatile char str[] = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rules 3 and 5.
- `char *str = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rules 3 and 1.
- `const char *str = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rules 3, 1, and 5.
- `volatile char *str = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rules 3, 1, and 5.
- `const volatile char *str = "Hello, world!\n"`, due to rules 3, 1, and 5.

Given rules 4 and 5, a call to `void fit(char*, int)` shall fail if the expression assigned to the first argument is non-qualified, such as if given the statement `const char *mesg = "Hey, Lisa. You look so beautiful!";`, the variable name `mesg` is assigned to the first argument in a call to `void fit(char*, int)`.

Just for completeness, rule 1 is strongered by rule 2, as seen in the expression `*(p + n) = '\0'` whenever `p` was degraded from an array at its assignment.

**tl;dr**: Most differences between both of the situations you described occur whenever a mismatch of qualifiers occur, as described in rule 5 above. This is mostly due to "historical reasons" (i.e: lazyness), and has affected other languages. For example, C++ saves some "compatibility with C", or in other words, compatibility with lazyness.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *mesg = "Hey, Lisa. You look so beautiful! "; // Line A
```

Here, this is *string literal* , thus a constant and you cannot modify its value.

What you can't do is -

```
mesg[0]='A';
```

And also what you have done in your code is wrong-

```
*(p + n) = '\0';   // equivalent to p[n]
```

`mesg[]="Hey, Lisa. You look so beautiful! ";  //  would be same as your declaration  if declared as const char mesg[]`

In this declaration  the expression is being used to initialize the contents another array, and is therefore not converted to a *pointer type* instead, the contents of the string literal are copied to `mesg`.

Comment: Although if the OP had declared it as `char mesg[]`, all you said here would be incorrect in such a case...

Comment: @KemyLand Please take a look. Yes I understand you point and I have made changes and thanks for your input :)

Comment: Yes, everything is now correct. Better edit than answer wrong :).