# How to change value in array with pointer?

Tags: c++

I have simply program to write. I try to make it with pointers. It is program which is changing uppercase to lowercase without index from function argument. Problem is with changing value, my program is crashing there...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char* male(char* nap, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if (i != n && ((*nap >= 'A') && (*nap <= 'Z'))) {
            *nap = (char)(*nap+32);
        }
        nap++;
    }
    return nap;
}

int main() {

    char * nap = "aBCDEFGHI";
    male(nap, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Could you tell me why `*nap = (char)(*nap+32);` is not a good way?

Comment: Because its ill formed

Comment: Why can't you just use `std::tolower`?

Comment: @Dr.Jones: What's ill-formed about it?

Comment: @lightness Poor choice of words. Its not ill-formed nor undefined behaviour because I have yet too see it result in anything but a crash. That's kind of the expected behaviour

Comment: @Dr.Jones: It's undefined behaviour. That you personally have _just so happened_ to see it result in a crash every time you personally have been observing, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is C++ code so following:

```
char * nap = "aBCDEFGHI";
```

should be

```
const char * nap = "aBCDEFGHI";
```

because string literals are const in C++. So your code :

```
*nap = (char)(*nap+32);
```

is also Undefined Behaviour, which can result in crash.

---

minimal change to remove UB is to define `nap` as array:

```
char nap[] = "aBCDEFGHI";
```

Comment: It can? It will! I have yet to see that code work anywhere

Comment: Thanks, I change my string.

Comment: @Dr.Jones: "Can" is correct. Never rely on any effects of any UB.

Comment: @Dr.Jones see here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0442ccec9da7a7d1, no segmentation fault, it will crash when string is sent to cout.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is supposed to complain of this line...

```
char * nap = "aBCDEFGHI";
```

Your major problem is that you are trying to modify a string literal at run-time. Its [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a?rq=1) to do so. See [Why is this string reversal C code causing a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1614739/1621391) explains your workaround.

> Could you tell me why `*nap = (char)(*nap+32);` is not a good way?

Its not all that bad per se. But you can get into trouble with it... That line is effectively...

```
*nap = *reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<char*>(nap+32));
```

C-style cast is a ruthless cast. as you can see, you are also casting away all `const` and/or `volatile` qualifications... There are some code bases that will hurt, especially if the object was stored in a read only marked memory... See [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used?rq=1)