# C - Replace multiple consecutive occurences of a character with single occurence

Tags: c, string, function, char, c-strings

How can I replace multiple consecutive occurences of a character with a single occurrence in C?

For example, if I have a `char myString[]="??hello?world????"` I would like to have the output as `?hello?world?`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112199/replace-consecutive-duplicate-character-with-its-single-occurance) link but it replaces a specific pattern. However, what if there are variable number of repeating characters?

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please try to create a [mcve] of your attempt to show us, describing the problems you have with it.

Comment: Would you consider 'l' as a repeating character in 'Hello'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using one loop.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *remove_duplicates(char *s, char c) {
    for (char *p = s, *q = s; *q;) {
        if (*++q != c || *p != c)
            *++p = *q;
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    char s[] = "??hello?world????";

    printf("\"%s\"\n", s);
    printf("\"%s\"\n", remove_duplicates(s, '?'));

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"??hello?world????"
"?hello?world?"
```

It is assumed that the null-terminating character should not be supplied as an argument of the function. Otherwise the function has no effect and returns the same string.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case additional answer
`"??hello?world????"`  ->  `"?helo?world?"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char myString[]="??hello?world????";
    int i,j,length=strlen(myString);
    char res[length];
    char prev;
    for(i=0,j=0;i<=length;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            prev=myString[i];
            res[j]=prev;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(prev!=myString[i])
            {

                res[j]=myString[i];
                prev=res[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s",res);
    return 0;
}
```